# IP Aliasing on different networks (windows)

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip-aliasing

My cousin works at a Municipality service and she asked me if I can help them upgrade their old Windows XP computers to new ones with Windows 7 and install them. It seemed like a pretty simple task so I agreed. Before installing the new PCs I copied the TCP/IP settings of the old PCs so I can use them on the new ones. The settings were the following:

```
IP: 192.168.1.x
Mask: 255.255.255.0
GATEWAY: 10.64.98.1
DNS: 10.95.1.16, 10.95.1.18
```

Upon further inspection I see that there are two IP address for each pc. The second was of the form

```
IP: 10.64.98.x
Mask: 255.255.254.0
```

I copy the exact same settings to the new PCs, but even though I can ping the Gateway, and the DNS servers, I can't ping anything on the internet. So they call the dude who supposedly had set up the network and he comes over does something which he wouldn't tell me what it is, and after that the computers could access the internet.

I check the TCP/IP settings and the routes, but they were unchanged from what I had set up.

Any ideas on what I could have missed which he corrected?

Also the PCs are on a local network with a 2003 Windows server running an oracle database and a shared folder. Even though I change the workgroup of the new PCs to the workgroup the old ones were, I can't see the shared folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a number of things. My first guess would be a proxy server. Check the Internet Explorer settings, or winhttp settings.

Comment: You were right they did use a proxy of the 10.x.x.x network.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have ONE gateway and since the gateway was assigned to the 192 address MAYBE (Really not sure) it had trouble getting outside the LAN.  He could have altered the routing tables.  Try running a route print on a non-fixed system and another on a fixed system and compare.